# Display image from network in ARCore

Tags: imageview, augmented-reality, android-glide, arcore, sceneform

I'm attempting to use Glide to fetch an image using HTTP and display it in AR using ARCore Sceneform. The layout file is working because the border described in it is being displayed, but the image itself is not being displayed or even fetched.

Here is my code:

```
View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.test_view, null);
      if (v == 2) {

          //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) renderable.getView();
           Glide.with(context)
                  .asDrawable()
                  .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
                  //.into(view);
                   .submit(-1,-1);

          rendobject =
                  ViewRenderable.builder()
                          .setView(context, view)
                          .setVerticalAlignment(ViewRenderable.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)
                          //.setSizer(new FixedWidthViewSizer(0.2f))
                          .setSizer(new FixedHeightViewSizer(0.15f))
                          .build()
                          .thenAccept(renderable -> {
                              testViewRenderable = renderable;
          });
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/planetInfoCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp"

    />
```

Here are the network permission declarations in the Manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I don't know what I'm missing/doing incorrectly.

Edit:
Here is something I also tried, but nothing is displayed after successfully scanning the augmented image:

```
rendobject =
                  ViewRenderable.builder()
                          .setView(context, R.layout.test_view)
                          .setVerticalAlignment(ViewRenderable.VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM)
                          .setSizer(new FixedHeightViewSizer(0.1f))
                          .build()
                          .thenAccept(renderable -> {
                              testViewRenderable = renderable;
                              ImageView imageView = (ImageView) renderable.getView();

                         Picasso.get()
                                 .load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
                                 .fit()
                                 .centerInside()
                                 .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that the Glide call and the view are connected in any way. You have to load the image into the ImageView.

Comment: That's actually what I tried before I tried this, but it does not display anything after successfully detecting the augmented image.

Updated question to show what I tried before this using Picasso.